# constructing a followers/following relationship

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

A relationship between users and followers is many-to-many.

My model:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username   string  `json:"username" gorm:"unique"`
    Name       string  `json:"name"`
    Followers  []*User `json:"followers" gorm:"many2many:user_followers"`
    Following  []*User `json:"following" gorm:"many2many:user_following"`
}
```

This model, when migrated, creates two junction tables which hold the user id and the follower/following id respectively.

Am I making a mistake by separating the Followers and Followings and in they are actually supposed to be just one table?

Comment: Followers are just other users, so it seems that one table would be sufficient.

Comment: Your final sentence doesn't make sense. Also this is not tagged with your language. PS What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck on what step among which steps following what published presentation of what design method/process given what? [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd follow the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) here and simplify the solution.

One table `followers` with `user_from_id,user_to_id,create_at,...` fields and with a `(user_from_id,user_to_id)` unique key should be enough. The `(user_from_id,user_to_id)` unique key will make sure that there are no duplicates.

Most likely you'll have 4 types of queries for this table:

1. Select current user followers `... WHERE user_to_id=%current_user_id% ...`
2. Select users followed by the current user `... WHERE user_from_id=%current_user_id% ...`
3. Check if the current user is following another user: `... WHERE user_from_id=%current_user_id% AND user_to_id=%another_user_id% ...`
4. Check if another user is following the current user: `... WHERE user_from_id=%another_user_id% AND user_to_id=%current_user_id% ...`

Cases 2,3,4 are already covered by the `(user_from_id,user_to_id)` unique key. However, you'll need an extra index (not unique, simple index will be enough) to optimise the 1st query: `(user_to_id)`.

Note: you may need extra indexes to optimise queries for your table. I assumed the most common use cases.